# Error: Android source build in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo, android-source

While trying to add android source to eclipse, I am getting the following errors.

```
Project 'android' is missing required library: 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/gsf-client_intermediates/javalib.jar'
Project 'android' is missing required library: 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/google-common_intermediates/javalib.jar'
```

FYI, I have built the source successfully with full_maguro-userdebug configuration (for Galaxy Nexus) before adding this to eclipse. Since I couldn't find "create project from existing source" in Eclipse Indigo, I changed the location of the project to the root directory of the source. I refreshed the project several times with same error.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: do you have any jar file attached/linked

Comment: You probably want to point to it for purpose of reference, not add it as a project (ie, that you would build from within eclipse)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should go to `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path`.

There open tab `Libraries`.

In this tab `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/google-common_intermediates/javalib.jar` should be changed to `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-common_intermediates/javalib.jar` by selecting javalib.jar from google-common_intermediates, pressing Edit and selecting instead android-common_intermediates.

Entry with gsf-client_intermediates javalib.jar can be simply deleted.

Comment: May still have some issues after fixing this. For example, two missing occurences of EventLogTags.java in:
'
   com.android.providers.calendar
   com.android.providers.contacts
'
More details see here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/XIbR8ZKe7Tw

Answer (score 1):

A more comprehensive answer at here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/XIbR8ZKe7Tw

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend using eclipse for android source. Android is not a single project and it too big for an IDE like eclipse to handle.

Use simpler plain text editors like vim, emacs to browse the code