# Download android source code for 2.3.3 & open it as an eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, android-source

I found this http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html but it seems to have so many steps has to be done.

Is there another way of downloading android source version we need from a zip file or svn & build it as an eclipse project?

I downloaded source as jar and extracted source files from http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1 but could not open it as eclipse project.

What I need is to build customized android version of my own.

Comment: If that is to many steps already, you should stop thinking about building a customized Android version on your own, as that will involve even much more effort afterwards (getting drivers for your specific device and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to follow instructions in  http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html It's really simple: you just need to create a new folder, init it and download the sources.

After that you can follow the instructions http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html to add your project into eclipse. You will face with some errors (the errors and my answer how to solve them is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369741/error-android-source-build-in-eclipse/10383282#10383282)).

Comment: Thanks Yury. But I am currently on Windows. If I do this using Linux can I stop this up to "Using authentication" topic in http://source.android.com/source/downloading.htm?

Comment: Yep. You do not need to be authenticated if you're not going to submit patches. Be careful, under Windows you cannot build Android. It is possible only in Linux or in Mac OS.