# android build error

Tags: android, java

I have created some modules inside android to add some additional
functionality.

I have defined my own make file but that doesn't have anything
like `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/My_featuers_intermiediates/
javalib.jar`.

When I am building my app I am getting errors like the following:

> No rule to make target 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/
>     my_featuers_intermiediates/javalib.jar' needed by 'out/target/common/
>     obj/APPS/My_features_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar'

What could be my mistake?

Comment: Do you have any external libs linked in?
[This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369741/error-android-source-build-in-eclipse) might be same problem?

Comment: yes actually i have addded an applcation of gingerbread so m getting some errors while building

Comment: Can someone tell me how to remove dependency of any jar file so that it doesnt get called